# CSS : Are there any possibilities to set element property as other class

Tags: css

Are there any opportunities to write styles like :

```
.green-button {
 color:green;
}

.login-button {
  .green-button
}
```

Comment: nope not possible in CSS, better use SASS where you can define variables.

Comment: You can't, but you can do that in this way:
.login-button, .green.button{
color: green;
}

Comment: Thanks for comments. I guess SASS help me.